# Create a parent from child elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say i have a list of ids [[1,2],[4,5,6]]

I am trying to create a parent element for each set of ids, say a div

currently its:

```
<span id="data-inject">
   <br> <br>
    <span id=1>Barack</span>
    <br> <br>
    <span id=2>Obama</span>
    <span id=3>xx</span>
<span>
```

I would like it to be:

```
   <span id="data-inject">
   <br> <br>
    <div id=test>
        <span id=1>Barack</span>
        <br> <br>
        <span id=2>Obama</span>
    </div>
    <span id=3>xx</span>
    </span>
```

is there any way to achieve the same using java script?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="data-inject"><br> <br> <span id="0">xx</span>&nbsp;<span id="1">Barack</span>&nbsp;<span id="2">Obama</span>&nbsp;<span id="3">xx</span>&nbsp;<span id="4">Barack</span>&nbsp;<span id="5">Obama</span>&nbsp;<span id="6">Barack</span>&nbsp;<span id="7">Obama</span><br> <br> <span id="8">sdsds</span>&nbsp;<span id="9">Barack</span>&nbsp;<span id="10">Obama</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#data-inject').find('span').slice(0,2).wrapAll('<div id="test"></div>').after(' ');
```

Here is a Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8L1mutxr/

> .after(' ')

add spaces after elements. But your HTML is very dirty by the way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but, I have some white space in the snippet this messes that up.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can easily create a new element for each array item and then loop through the inner array to search and append to the newly create item,

the example should be auto explanatory:

```js
var arr = [[1,2],[4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]]

arr.forEach((x, i) => {
  // we create a parent div for each item
  var parent = $('<div class="parent'+ i + '"></div>')
  // we append it 
  $('#data-inject').append(parent)
  
  // we loop through inner arrays and append them to newly created 'parent'
  x.forEach(z => {
    parent.append( $('#' + z) )
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="data-inject">
  <span id="0">xx</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="1">Barack</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="2">Obama</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="3">xx</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="4">Barack</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="5">Obama</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="6">Barack</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="7">Obama</span>
  <span id="8">sdsds</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="9">Barack</span>&nbsp;
  <span id="10">Obama</span>
</span>
```